# How to ignorecase when using string.text.contains?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I am trying to figure out how to check if a string contains another while ignoring case using .text.contains.

As it stands right now If I do this:

```
 Dim myhousestring As String = "My house is cold"
    If txt.Text.Contains(myhousestring) Then
    Messagebox.Show("Found it")
    End If
```

It will only return a match if it is the exact same case. So if the user typed "my house is cold", it would not be a match.

How can I do this? If it is not possible I could probably just use regex instead with ignorecase. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224424.aspx) you can do case-insensitive searches in strings with `IndexOf` instead of `Contains`. So when the result  of the `IndexOf` method returns a value greater than `-1`, it means the second string is a substring of the first one.

```
Dim myhousestring As String = "My house is cold"
If txt.Text.IndexOf(myhousestring, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 Then
    Messagebox.Show("Found it")
End If
```

You can also use other case-insensitive variants of [StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx).

Comment: ahh, this is exactly what I was looking for. I knew their was was another string method that could be used to compare strings. Thanks alot. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not a vb.net programmer, but according to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312897), you can get the lowercase/uppercase value of the text using the string methods `ToUpper()` or `ToLower()`.  You can then compare that with `"my house is cold"` or `"MY HOUSE IS COLD"`.

```
Dim myhousestring As String = "MY HOUSE IS COLD"
If txt.Text.ToUpper.Contains(myhousestring) Then
    Messagebox.Show("Found it")
End If
```

Comment: I like this solution better.

Comment: This causes issues w/ globalization specifically w/ Turkish i. I'd be careful w/ this method.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I just used:

```
item.Text.ToLower().Contains("my house is cold")
```

you could just as well use ToUpper as well.

Caveat: If you are comparing Turkish, or other languages, the ToLower() and ToUpper() also take an option parameter, for "CultureInfo" allowing you to ensure that different languages are handled correctly.
You can use an above solution, or you can follow the steps from Microsoft's ToLower Documentation, to add in CultureInfo, to get ToLower context on which language you are about to try to manipulate.

[ToLower() with CultureInfo documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8z5yt00(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ToUpper() with CultureInfo documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24kc78ka(v=vs.110).aspx/)

Comment: This causes issues w/ globalization specifically w/ Turkish i. I'd be careful w/ this method.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to mention that it needs to support Turkish... especially when we are comparing the text, with English... The Culture indifferent compare isn't going to translate from Turkish to English, and THEN compare, it's just going to compare the characters.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with .toUpper

For example:

```
Dim UGroup as String = dr.Item(2).ToString().ToUpper
Dim s as String = ds.Item(1).ToString.ToUpper

If s.Contains(UGroup) then MsgBox("Well done!")
Else 
End Sub
```

Same procedure with .toLower

Comment: Sorry it's a german word. Commata means Commas.
So "," this is only importan in my code. But i deleted it to not spread confusion.

Comment: Danke für das +1! I mean: Thank you for the +1

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use RegularExpressions like this.

First, import the RegularExpressions:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

then try this code:

```
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(Textbox1.text,"My house is cold",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
If match.Success Then
   Msgbox(match.Value)
End If
```

Comment: this looks like an overkill

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved my problem of making String.Contains become case insensitive.

```
Dim s as string = "My HoUsE iS cOlD".ToUpper

If s.Contains("MY HOUSE IS COLD") Then Exit Sub
```

For my particular issue, the string that I was checking was housed within a TextBox.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Function InStr(s As String, find As String) As Boolean
    Return s.ToLower.Contains(find.ToLower)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

use the InStr example. "contains" fails if ether compare is nothing.

'if we found something...

```
If InStr(1, value, search, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

Beep

End If   

                                               '
```

Comment: InStr's first parameter isn't needed in this case, and you might want to match up your input parameters with the questions. I also don't think this is case-insensative according to MSDN?

Answer (score 0):

I use below code to search/confirm if string in TEXTBOX1 was in "c:\testsearch.txt".

```
    Imports System.IO

Private Function sinf(path As String, match As String) As Boolean 
    Dim s As String = File.ReadAllText(path).ToLower
    Return s.Contains(match.ToLower)
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim st As String
    st = TextBox1.Text
    If sinf("c:\testsearch.txt", st) = True Then 
        MsgBox("Found if")
    Else
        MsgBox("Try again")
    End If
End Sub
```