# Make checking a string not case sensitive

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program which a user enters an item in a text box and the program will check if the item is in the string. Here is my current code:

```
     Try
        Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.dropbox.com/s/2l37j6v0ofsenus/Foods.txt?dl=1")
        Dim Response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream)
        Dim Foods As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
        If Foods.Contains(TXTItem1.Text) Then
            Dim Substring As String = Foods.Split(TXTItem1.Text)(1)
            Dim SubString1 As String = Substring.Split("-")(1)
            Dim SPValue As String = SubString1.Split(vbNewLine)(0)
            MsgBox("That item is worth " + SPValue + " SmartPoints!", info)
        Else
            MsgBox("Item is not found in our list!", critical)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try
```

I want to make it where when it checks the string, it is not case sensitive. So if a user enters "eggs" and the string contains "Eggs", it will do the function still even tho its lower-case. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: This should answer the question pretty sufficiently: [How to ignorecase when using string.text.contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064189/how-to-ignorecase-when-using-string-text-contains)

Comment: Also more examples of how to use indexof on this MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

The linked question that's referred to by @jacob-h in [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333408/make-checking-a-string-not-case-sensitive#comment89642621_51333408) already has answers to your question, but I prefer an extension method in this case.

Here's an extension method version that I've been using for a while. Add a new Module to your project (or use an existing one if you find it appropriate), and add this extension method to it:

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function ContainsIgnoreCase(ByVal s As String, ByVal value As String)
    Return s.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
End Function
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
If Foods.ContainsIgnoreCase(TXTItem1.Text) Then
    ' Do your thing.
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the string you're testing to lowercase, and also the string you are testing against to lowercase, then case is no longer a consideration!

There are functions that can do this for you, but the logic behind them is always the same ... Caseless comparison requires both pieces of data to be converted to either all lowercase (or all uppercase), before the comparison is undertaken. I

Comment: That idea goes wrong with some cultures, as explained in [Jon Skeet - "Back to basics: the mess we've made of our fundamental data types"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3nPJ-yK-LU) on YouTube. (It's best to watch it all, but the part regarding text starts at about 12:20.)