# VB.Net LINQ on List(Of structure) - one field contains text from another field

Tags: linq, vb.net-2010

I have a list (of structure)

```
 Dim gBookList As List(Of mystructure) = myarr.ToList
```

gBookList has 2 fields - 'FirstName' and 'LastName'.

I want to filter those records where FirstName field contains values from the LastName field. I tried the below but does not seem to work although it is easy in SQL, i am unable to do same with LINQ.

```
gBookList = gBookList.Where(Function(value) value.FirstName.Contains(value.LastName)).ToList
```

I am sure this is not the right syntax, i tried searching online but did not get working results.

Comment: Seems correct. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Is it's Entity Framework, you could use `EF.Like` inside lambda.

Comment: No error message. But results are blank. There are many matching records

Comment: if you need case insensitive contains, you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064189/how-to-ignorecase-when-using-string-text-contains

Comment: Any suggestions please... above are not helping much