# What to do to be able to search a word from label in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, search, textbox, label

I'm trying to check if the label contains certain word, how can I do that?

I have label1 with Text: THIS IS YOUR LAST TEST
I have blank textbox1 for searching
I have button1 to search the input text on textbox1 from label1.

For example, I want to search "LAST", how can I do that?

```
If I type LAST on the textbox1 Then
If label1 have the word typed on textbox1 Then
Msgbox("You found me")
End If
```

Can you help me?
I'm new and I'm using VB net

Comment: [How to ignorecase when using string.text.contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064189/how-to-ignorecase-when-using-string-text-contains) might give you useful ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    If label1.Text.IndexOf(textbox1.Text) <> -1 Then
        MsgBox("Your Message.")
    End If
```

OR

```
    If Not string.isNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text) andAlso label1.Text.ToUpper.Contains(textbox1.Text.ToUpper) Then
        MsgBox("Your Message.")
    End If
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd code but it always work even I don't type any letter on the textbox1.
Even the input word is not the same on the label, it shows the MsgBox.
Matching or not Matching, it shows the msgbox.
I think this is not the correct code.

The first code is correct. But it can't search if the letter is lower case or upper case like the text on the label

Comment: I edited my solution above slightly. I assumed you would not allow submission with an empty text box. A check for `Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.text) ` should handle it.

Comment: The code works. Thank you. But what if the situation is, I want to automatically change the combobox selected item if the label1 contains specific word put directly on the code, not in the textbox1. How is that sir?

Comment: You'd need to open ask a new question with code samples/attempts and some more context. :) SO is here to help you answer questions, now just answer them for you. It sounds like you should look into a basic asp.net / vb.net tutorial.